# Specified folder/zip file does not contain a valid library

Tags: library

I am trying to use [this](https://github.com/mikedotalmond/arduino-pulseInWithoutDelay) library. 
But when I try to import the .zip file (of the directory) downloaded from GitHub, Arduino IDE says "Specified folder/zip file does not contain a valid library"

Comment: This problem really annoying. i can't add any library except from Arduino ide it self. even the most common library not even work, it seems to be a glitched or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because it contains *two* libraries, and the IDE doesn't know how to handle that.

Because of this repository structure, you will need to do a [manual installation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/guide/libraries#toc5).

Extract the zip file manually and copy the `libraries` folder into your Arduino sketchbook folder. You can find the location of your sketchbook folder in the Arduino IDE at **File > Preferences > Sketchbook location**.

Comment: To be more exact: Copy the content of the `libraries` folder into the `Arduino/libraries` folder in your system

Comment: @chrisl Nah - just copy the folder. If it doesn't already exist it will do after copying it. If it does exist the OS will just merge the folders together, effectively copying the contents.